# Any way to save HashAlgorithm state

Tags: .net, serialization, hashalgorithm

I have an ASP.Net web service with chunked file uploads.
I'm trying to calculate hash for file while uploading in static HashAlgorithm instance.
This instance disposes each time app pool beign reseted.
That's why I want to keep current state for HashAlgorithm instance.

Is there a way to save .Net HashAlgoritm state?

Application #1

```
....

var alg = HashAlgorithm.Create();
alg.Initialize();
alg.TransformBlock(someData...);

StoreSomeHow(alg)

alg.Dispose();
```

Application #2

```
RestoreSomeHow(out alg);
alg.TransformFinalBlock(someData...);
var hash = alg.Hash;
```

It looks weird, I know )

Comment: If you could explain what you were trying to achieve, that would be a good starting point.

Comment: a "good starting point" added

Comment: Why not hash it *after* you've uploaded the whole file?

Comment: That's a "Plan B".   Because file also beign zipped on server side,  I don't want to unzip it again just to hash it

Comment: Are you zipping incrementally, or only after the file has been uploaded? I'd be tempted to upload all the chunks, then hash and zip at the same time.

Comment: I'm zipping it incrementally

Comment: So as I say, I wouldn't do that. I suspect that makes the zipping code more complicated than it needs to be, as well as the hashing code. If you just have an area of the server which contains partial uploads, it needn't get very big - then for each file you can read through the whole thing *once* after the upload has completed, zipping it, hashing it and anything else you want to do along the way... then delete it.

Comment: Assuming your larger design is valid (I have my doubts), you should replace the .NET HashAlgorithm by some other implementation. BouncyCastle has a bunch, and since it's open source you can add a state saving feature if it's lacking one.